# How to increase timeout for "Timeout error occurred trying to stop MySQL Daemon."

Tags: mysql, timeout

When I run `/etc/init.d/mysqld stop`, I get this error: `Timeout error occurred trying to stop MySQL Daemon.`

Is there any way to increase that timeout?

Comment: On what Linux distribution?

Comment: This was RHEL6, but applied to Fedora too. I found /etc/sysconfig/mysqld by looking at the code in /etc/init.d/mysqld

Answer (score 1):

Found my answer:

The timeout can be set in `/etc/sysconfig/mysqld`

```
STARTTIMEOUT=240
STOPTIMEOUT=240
```